# Linq on Custom Class List

Tags: c#, linq

How would I edit the method `ClosestColor` to accept the parameter `List<DuluxColours>` instead of `List<Color>`?

I need the method `ClosestColor` to return the color name from my `List<DuluxColours>`

Is this even possible? My Linq proficiency is somewhat lacking :)

Thanks for any help!

```
public int ClosestColor(List<Color> colours, Color target)
{

    var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n, target)).Min(n => n);
    return colours.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n, target) == colorDiffs);
}

public int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2)
{
    return (int)Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R)
                           + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
                           + (c1.B - c2.B) * (c1.B - c2.B));
}

public class DuluxColour
{
    public string ColourName { get; set; }
    public Color Colour { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think all you need to do is:
    var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target)).Min(n => n.Colour);
    return colours.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) == colorDiffs);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public DuluxColour ClosestColor(List<DuluxColour> colours, Color target)
{
    var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target)).Min(n => n);
    return colours.Find(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) == colorDiffs);
}
```

Note that I chose to return `DuluxColour` instead of just the name so callers have the option to get the color value. In your case you will need to call:

```
string closestColorName = ClosestColor(colours, target).ColourName;
```

Take note that you have the handle the possibility of `ClosestColor` returning null.

Without using an explicit `List`, you can also use:

```
public DuluxColour ClosestColor(IEnumerable<DuluxColour> colours, Color target)
{
    var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target)).Min(n => n);
    return colours.FirstOrDefault(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) == colorDiffs);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Also note that OP can simplify their code. Currently we have two iterations over the colours (one to find the min, the second to find which colour has the min difference). This can be simplified to something like `return colours.Select(n => new { Colour = n, Diff = ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Diff).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Rob :)

Answer (score -1):

You May Try this,

```
public int ClosestColor(List<DuluxColour> colours, Color target)
    {

        var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target)).Min(n => n);
        return colours.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) == colorDiffs);
    }
```

I hope this may work for you

Answer (score -1):

```
     public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Your code goes here
                Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
                List<DuluxColour> _colors= new List<DuluxColour>();
                _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Black , ColourName ="Black"});
                    _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Red , ColourName ="Red"});
                    _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Green , ColourName ="Green"});
                    _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Yellow , ColourName ="Yellow"});
                var col =ClosestColor(_colors, Color.Purple);
                Console.Write(col.ColourName);
            }
            public static DuluxColour ClosestColor(List<DuluxColour> colours, Color target)
            {

                var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target)).Min(n => n);
                return colours.Find(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) == colorDiffs);
            }

            public static int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2)
            {
                return (int)Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R)
                                       + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
                                       + (c1.B - c2.B) * (c1.B - c2.B));
            }


        }


  public class DuluxColour
        {
            public string ColourName { get; set; }
            public Color Colour { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
you can still do,    

  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            List<DuluxColour> _colors= new List<DuluxColour>();
            _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Black , ColourName ="Black"});
                _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Red , ColourName ="Red"});
                _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Green , ColourName ="Green"});
                _colors.Add(new DuluxColour{Colour = Color.Yellow , ColourName ="Yellow"});
            var col =ClosestColor(_colors, Color.Purple);
            Console.Write(col);
        }
        public static string ClosestColor(List<DuluxColour> colours, Color target)
        {

            var colorDiffs = colours.Select(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target)).Min(n => n);
            return colours.FirstOrDefault(n => ColorDiff(n.Colour, target) == colorDiffs).ColourName;
        }

        public static int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2)
        {
            return (int)Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R)
                                   + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
```